# Socket, connect and disconnect

Tags: java, android, kotlin, socket.io

I'm currently working on a project that send files to server via socket.
In project I create a **SenderManager** that contains a list of files for sending and it's updating any moment a file is available.
which one is a good approach for having a better performance:

1- connect and disconnect socket **for every file** I want to send

2- connect socket and **keep it alive until sending all files** and then disconnect it.

Comment: If you just try them both you can tell us.

Comment: In short run, both of them are similar, I'm looking for an answer for long run.